# Center Raised Button disturbed other buttons in tabbar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

[image]

The center raised button is at it's perfect state. But now the rest of the buttons like chat and menu are disturbed and are not tappable now. I used [this library](https://github.com/singer1026/IrregularTabbarCustom) for the center raised button. If you look at this library there is a file `LCTabbar.m` on which there is a method named `addBarButtons` which is the one I modified according to the icons I required.

```
-(void) addBarButtons{


    UIColor *bgColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:112/255.0 green:106/255.0 blue:92/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    UIColor *fgColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:201/255.0 green:192/255.0 blue:173/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    [[UITabBar appearance] setBarTintColor:bgColor];
    [[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:fgColor];


    for (int i = 0 ; i<4 ; i++) {
        LCTabBarButton *btn = [[LCTabBarButton alloc] init];
        CGFloat btnW = self.frame.size.width/4;
        CGFloat btnX = i * btnW;
        CGFloat btnY = 0;

        CGFloat btnH = self.frame.size.height;

        btn.frame = CGRectMake(btnX, btnY, btnW, btnH);
//        NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"TabBar%d",i+1];
//        NSString *selImageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"TabBar%dSel",i+1];
        NSString *title;

//        if (i==0) {
//            [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"horn-big"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
//            [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"horn-big"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
//            
//            
//        }
        if(i==1){
            title = @"Chat";
            [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"speech_bubble"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"speech_bubble"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
            }
        else if(i==2){
//            imageName = @"horn-big";
//            selImageName =@"megaphone-1";
            title = @"Menu";
            [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"list_filled"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"list_filled"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        }
        else if(i==3){
            title = @"Settings";
            [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"settings_filled"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"settings_filled"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

        }
//        else if(i==4){
//            title = @"Settings";
//            [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"settings_filled"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
//            [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"settings_filled"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
//            [btn setTintColor:fgColor];
//        }


        btn.tag = i;
        if (i!=0) {
            [btn setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            btn.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize: 11.0];
            btn.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
            [btn setTitleColor:RGB(201, 192, 173) forState:UIControlStateSelected];
            [btn setTitleColor:RGB(201, 192, 173) forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [self addSubview:btn];

            //[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(btnClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
        }
        btn.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        [self addSubview:btn];

//        if(i == 0){
//            [self btnClick:btn];
//        }
    }
}
```

As you can see I have commented the some sections which I didn't require. As I don't want any icon at left of the chat it'll be blank so the index `0` is commented and for the rest I've changed the name and icon. Other commented out code was the default library code which I didn't needed. So I can't seems to figure out where the problem is.

Comment: bring the tab bar buttons to front and try.

Comment: @Signare how to do that?